# Why do AWS recommend public and private subnets with a nat gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, nat, subnet, private-subnet

I'll be complying with AWS best practise and having e.g. database instances inside a private subnet but I am wondering why this architecture is recommended?

[image]

AWS recommend this architecture so that the DBMS is not accessible to the outside world. If you want to patch it, or some other operation and it needs access to the internet, you should provision a NAT gateway in your public subnet. The DBMS instance in the private subnet can then get access to internet through this NAT gateway.

Could the same be achieved via security groups with the DBMS instance in the public subnet? It's worth noting that AWS charge around 40 USD / month for a NAT gateway.

On the DBMS instance you could have a security group rule which allows all outbound traffic but blocks inbound traffic (which I think is the default rule). This rule could be extended to only allow inbound traffic from a specific web server in the public subnet.

Is the answer that instances inside a public subnet automatically get a public IPv4 address? This would be undesirable for my DBMS instance even though it is effectively fire-walled through my security group rules as outlined above.

Thanks for your help in assisting me to understand AWS networking better.

Comment: from technical perspective, putting in public subnet with the right rules would work. However, you never know the vulnerability issue your DB might expose and if someone messes up the rules of your security group, you can easily expose it to the world.

Comment: You can use a NAT instance rather than a NAT gateway if you prefer. Using a very small instance type, perhaps `t4g.nano`, will only cost about $3/mo. But that small of an instance type will only be helpful for the least demanding use cases.

Answer (score 4):

You are right that this is the reference architecture, and you are indeed the not the first person to raise an eyebrow regarding the cost for the NAT Gateway.

It is true that the separation of public and private networks is an additional security layer that can prevent inadvertent exposure of your critical infrastructure to the public internet, but also to less privileged resources in your VPC.

Keep in mind that not every private subnet needs a NAT gateway; this is only necessary if the machines need to initiate traffic to the internet themselves. You could for example have pre-baked, regularily updated AMIs that don’t need the usual `yum update` at boot or any other such activities, and you might get away without the NAT Gateway.

Also, best practices doesn’t mean that it’s mandatory. For instance, if you deploy via Cloudformation, do regular security and architectural reviews and are sure to have SGs/NACLs/etc. set up properly, you could place the database in a “public” subnet as well. TL;DR: Use your own judgement to assess the tradeoff between security and cost, one way or the other.

*Disclaimer: This is not the official position of AWS but my personal perspective.*